# C# - connecting to a MySQL database in a remote computer

Tags: c#, mysql, database

Good day;
I am making an C# desktop application using MySQL as database. The execution works fine when using local server "localhost", but I want to install it in other computers and keep the database in my computer.
I proceeded like following to allow other computers to connect the database :

- I added a new user to the database and gave it all required permissions.
- I added the IP address of the computer in which the database exist
  This is the connection string :

> ```
> String connString = "Server = '192.168.xxx.xxx';  "
>                      + "Port = '3306'; "
>                      + "Database = 'mydb'; "
>                      + "uid = 'dbUser'; "
>                      + "pwd = 'userPassword';"
>                      + "Persist Security Info=true;";
> ```

From the computer in which the database is installed, I can execute without any problem but from other computers I can not connect to the database. It gave me the error :

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

- Computers are in network but not in the same domain network.
- There is no problem with the port.

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: BTW, I don't think `Persist Security Info` is applicable for MySQL.

Comment: Can you connect using MySQL Workbench or the like? That's how you determine the appropriate connection string. If you can connect from a management tool like that then programming languages in general are irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: the problem may be different domain networks or firewall blocking traffic. I suggest adding tags ip, internet, dns to the entry

Comment: You can check connection by `telnet`, or `Test-NetConnection 192.168.xxx.xxx -Port 3306`. 
Have you verified that MySQL Server is configured to accept remote connections?
I'm not sure if in the case of different domains connected in a network, you don't need to configure something additionally - e.g. routing, unblocking ports. Maybe you could write how these domains are networked? how is routing set up? Is traffic on any port between machines working? Or maybe you need to refer to the name and configure internal DNS.

Comment: @MickyD, even when removing the `Persist Security Info`, the same error occur.

Comment: @jimcilhinney, 
There is no problem with the `connectionstring` because the code is executed without problems in the computer where database is installed.

Comment: _"the same error occur"_ - that's because mine was a **by the way** _comment_ and **not** an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I resolved the problem.
The problem was the port 3306 should be authorized by the firewall of the computer in which the database is installed.
For those who got the same problem, this is the way how to resolve it :

- Open `firewall` >> `Advanced settings`
- Right click on `Inbound Rules` and choose the first option `New Rule`.
- Check the second option `Port`, then click Next button
- Be sure that `TCP` option is checked, then check `Specific local ports` and add the port 3306. Then Next and the port 3306 will be authorized and the connection from other computers permitted.